# Is there an app that will track "Time since last full charge" on OS X?

Tags: macos, battery, utilities

I am trying to troubleshoot battery life issues in OS X Lion on my MBA13. Is there an app (or hidden system information) that can tell me how long my computer has been on since last full charge. I am not looking for uptime, but looking specifically for Time Since Last Full Charge, just as is available in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [MiniBatteryLogger](http://www.emeraldion.it/software/macosx/minibatterylogger.html)

It helped me troubleshoot my battery issues. I'm not sure it will do exactly what you asked for but when you have it running (on battery or power adapter):

> MiniBatteryLogger monitors your laptop’s battery, traces the graph of charge and amperage over time, compares your battery with other users, logs relevant power events and alerts you with Growl notifications.

[image]

And right now it's even free:

> We are undergoing some changes and cannot issue licenses.
>   … In the meantime, you can use this evaluation key:

[Register MiniBatteryLogger](http://www.emeraldion.it/software/macosx/minibatterylogger/register.html)

Answer (score 5):

Everything you need is provided with OS X.

For graphical details and an overview, open **Activity Monitor** and the energy tab lists the time you have been on your current power source:

[image]

In my case, it was showing 5 hours on AC power, so I disconnected the charger to show that the battery is just starting up. The graph on the right will give you a nice history if you go between multiple charge/drain events over the last 12 hours.

For details, use the `pmset` command in terminal app:

```
pmset -g log
```

Since that log is verbose, you might start with filtering the messages about **Using**

```
pmset -g log | grep Using
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [Battery Logger](https://itunes.apple.com/tw/app/battery-logger/id473673114?mt=12) by Ananta Sjartuni does exactly what I want.